# How to send values from autocomplete search with jquery to a controller in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring, autocomplete

I have have a search table with two autocomplete fields for searching user within the fields.
The table and the autocomplete working great. But my question is how i can get the values from the search fields and with only one button save them in database?
How can I get the values from the search?

Here are my codes :

autocomplete.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"    import="java.util.*"%>
    ......
  </head>


  <script type='text/javascript'>
$().ready(function() {
    $('#search_input').focus()
});// focus search area
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
$().ready(function() {
    $('#blocked').focus()
});// focus search area
  </script>

 <style type="text/css">
 .halfDiv {
padding: 1em;
width: 42%;
float: left;
   }
.rightDiv {
padding: 1em;
width: 7%;
float: right;
  }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="halfDiv">
 <div id='header'>
 <h1 class="font2">Blocker User</h1>
 <form action='javascript:void(0);'>
<h3> <input id='search_input' size="32" style="height:20px"   name='search_input' type='text' autocomplete="on" />
 </h3>
 </form>
</div>
<div style="clear:left; height:30px;"></div>
<c:forEach items="${imageList}" var="blocker_images">
<div id='content'>
<div class='volcano search_item'>
<h4 class='search_text'>
<div class=fontstyle >
  ${blocker_images.user.userid }                            
 ${blocker_images.user.firstname } 
 ${images.user.lastname}
 ${blocker_images.user.email }
</div>
</h4>
<div class="infor_div">
<img alt="pictures" src="<c:url value='${request.contextPath}/image/${blocker_images.imageid}'/>" />    </div>
<div class="picture_div">
<p>${blocker_images.user.address.street }<br/>${blocker_images.user.address.zipcode }    ${blocker_images.user.address.city }</p> </div>
</div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
</div>
<div class="halfDiv">
<div id='header'>
<h1 class="font2">Blocked User</h1>
<form action='javascript:void(0);'>
<h3>
<input id='blocked' size="32" style="height:20px" name='blocked' type='text' autocomplete="off" />
</h3>
</form>
</div>
<div style="clear:left; height:30px;"></div>
<c:forEach items="${imageList}" var="blocked_images">
<div id='content'>
<div class='volcano search_item_blocked'>
<h4 class='search_text_blocked'>
<div class="fontstyle">
${blocked_images.user.userid }
${blocked_images.user.firstname }
${blocked_images.user.lastname} ${blocked_images.user.email }</div>
</h4>
<div class="picture_div">
<img alt="pictures" src="<c:url value='${request.contextPath}/image/${blocked_images.imageid}'/>"/>
</div>
<div class="infor_div">                                   
${blocked_images.user.address.street }
 ${blocked_images.user.address.city } ${blocked_images.user.address.zipcode }</p>
</div></div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
</div>
<form:form action="" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
        <div  class="rightDiv"> <button class="button blue" type="submit">Save</button></div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Here is The autocomplete.js

```
$().ready(function(){
// Instant Search
$('#search_input').keyup(function(){
$('.search_item').each(function(){
  var re = new RegExp($('#search_input').val(), 'i');
  if($(this).children('.search_text')[0].innerHTML.match(re)){
    $(this).show();
  }else{
    $(this).hide();
  };
 });
 });
});
 $().ready(function(){
// Instant Search
$('#blocked').keyup(function(){
    $('.search_item_blocked').each(function(){
        var re = new RegExp($('#blocked').val(), 'i');
        if($(this).children('.search_text_blocked')[0].innerHTML.match(re)){
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        };
    });
});
   });
```

here is my Controller

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping
 public class BlockeeController
 {
@Autowired
private static BlockeeService blockeeService = new BlockeeService();
@Autowired
private static UserService us = new UserService();
@Autowired
private static DisplayImageService imgService = new DisplayImageService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/autocomplete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String autocomplete(@ModelAttribute("blocker") User  blocker,     @ModelAttribute("blocked") User blocked, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("blocker "+blocker);
    System.out.println("blocked "+blocked);

    model.addAttribute("currentUser", getCurrentUsername());

    Collection<User> users = us.findAllUsers();
    model.addAttribute("allUsers", users);

    Collection<UploadImage> imageList = imgService.showAllPictures();
    model.addAttribute("imageList", imageList);
            model.addAttribute("blocker", blocker);
    model.addAttribute("blocked", blocked);

    return "autocomplete";

}
```

The question here is: what should it be here @RequestParam or @ModelAttribute?
Can I have two different Modelattribute ? I just wrote some code here as example.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/autocomplete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String blockeeImages(@ModelAttribute("blocker") User  blocker, @ModelAttribute("blocked") User blocked, Model model)
{

    System.out.println(blocker);
    System.out.println(blocked);
    model.addAttribute("currentUser", getCurrentUsername());


    UploadImage blockerImage = imgService.showImageByUserId(blocker.getUserid());
    model.addAttribute("blockerImage", blockerImage.getImageid());
    model.addAttribute("blockerUser", blockerImage);

    UploadImage blockedImage = imgService.showImageByUserId(blocked.getUserid());
    model.addAttribute("blockedImage", blockedImage.getImageid());
    model.addAttribute("blockedUser", blockedImage);

    Blockee blockee= new Blockee(blocker,blocked);
    blockeeService.addUserToBlockee(blockee);

    return "/blockeeIndex";
}


private String getCurrentUsername()
{
    Object obj = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return obj instanceof UserDetails ? ((UserDetails) obj).getUsername() : obj.toString();
}

 }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the form is submitted as a POST but the controller expects a GET, also the action of the form is empty so the controller will never get hit. @RequestParameter is for GET parameters but this is a POST

Comment: have a look at this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/

Comment: HI
The first controller which is a GET is for getting the table with images and the second is POST which is for posting the form.
So that is not the problem. And I use @ModelAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned any `<form></form>` tags in your JSP page. Save button type is mentioned to be `Submit`, so add a form and get all the form attributes in controller using `@ModelAttribute` annotation, provided you write a POJO containing JSP attributes in it.

Other option is make an AJAX call on click of Save button. Prepare a Javascript object, assign variables to it along with values and stringify it. Stringify operation will convert it to JSON, pass this JSON to controller which will convert it to `Java Object` representing the Javascript object. Controller will accept this obkect using `@RequestBody` annotation.

Comment: Hi

Please check my codes I updated them.
But the problem is that I cant get the users with @ModelAttribute they are null.

The question how I get them after search.

I can not any Ajax. 

Please I you have more help will be great full.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the JSON representing the User that you want to retrieve in your controller.

For example if you send a JSON like this:

```
$.ajax({url:'autocomplete',
  type:'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType:'application/json',
  data:JSON.stringify([
                 {blockerImage : someValue, ... }
                 ,{blockerImage: otherValue, ...}])
});
```

(I'm assuming some values for the User POJO)

This will send to your controller a List of blocker objects you can retrieve them in your controller bi having something like this.

```
public String blockeeImages(@RequestBody List<User> blockerParams, Model model){

}
```

Having the POJO for your User object sending the JSON will create the user objects and then you can use them as you wish.

And add jackson-mapper to your project to work more easily with JSON reprentations.